# "Add Media" button in custom plugin

Tags: plugins, uploads, media

I'm writing a custom plugin and i would like to add the "Add Media" button.

I just need to upload media, not to retrieve any content/data from the uploaded file.

How can I add this button?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to add a add media button to your **admin** panels:

You need to use wp_enqueue_media();

```
add_action ( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    if (is_admin ())
        wp_enqueue_media ();
} );
```

Then use this js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $ = jQuery;
    if ($('.set_custom_images').length > 0) {
        if ( typeof wp !== 'undefined' && wp.media && wp.media.editor) {
            $('.set_custom_images').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var button = $(this);
                var id = button.prev();
                wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
                    id.val(attachment.id);
                };
                wp.media.editor.open(button);
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Use this html:

```
<p>
    <input type="number" value="" class="regular-text process_custom_images" id="process_custom_images" name="" max="" min="1" step="1">
    <button class="set_custom_images button">Set Image ID</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Perfect! I just wants to replace "$" with "jQuery" and everything works as expected! Thank you.

Comment: No need for `is_admin()` when you use the hook `admin_enqueue_scripts`. Also, I would check if you're on the correct page with `get_current_screen()`.

Comment: For anyone who, like me, may also need the URL for the image, you can use the following: `var attachmentURL = wp.media.attachment(attachment.id).get("url");`.  I put this inside `function(props, attachment)`

Comment: @seveninstl I use Worpdress 5.6 and `attachment.url` works. Is there any reason for using `wp.media.attachment(attachment.id).get("url")` ?

Answer (score 2):

***Show thumbnail preview instead of number***

Just as a tweak, I did this...

changed the number input to hidden.

added:

```
$imgid =(isset( $instance[ 'imgid' ] )) ? $instance[ 'imgid' ] : "";
$img    = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgid, 'thumbnail');
```

And then... above the hidden field.

```
if($img != "") {
?>
  <img src="<?= $img[0]; ?>" width="80px" /><br />
<?php 
}
```

That will make a thumbnail visible in the user end instead of a number :)